# Организация ЧПУ на страницы-фильтры. Выбор CMS

Tags: cms, seo

Планируется создание интернет-магазина.В будущем возможно продвижение страниц-фильтров с товарами. Есть ли такие CMS, которые могут из коробки, или с доустановкой модуля, прикручивать ЧПУ на страницы-фильтры, мета-тэги и прочую СЕОшную мутотень. Имеется в виду законченное решение, а не написание костылей в виде перехватчика контента.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из нового и развивающегося могу посоветовать DotPlant2. Уже из коробке есть такой функционал. Можно прописывать ЧПУ, H1, title, description, keywords для любого фильтра, соответственно. Документация у них есть, даже демку можно попробовать по адресу http://full-test.dotplant.ru/. Админка http://full-test.dotplant.ru/backend (admin ForDemoOnly).

Comment: Хороший пример.

Answer (score 0):

Русский перевод Opencart. OCstore+FilterPro (seo). В принципе не очень удобно но как вариант пойдёт.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?